# Where's the best place to share files from?

Tags: filesystem, windows, sharing, samba

I've got Samba installed on Ubuntu 10.04 and am about to configure it using webmin, but I just realized I don't know the best place to create a file share on a Linux system.

I want to use best practice as to not accidentally create a security risk or put a share in an unconventional place where an experienced Linux user would have a hard time finding it.

Basically I want to transfer some general files (pics, docs, etc) back and forth between a Ubuntu file share (placement TBD) and a Windows machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Often configurations are done that allow every user to have a `public` folder in their home directory. This way every user has control over their public files and no system files will ever be accessible there.

Comment: Ah yes, when I look in my home folder there's already a public folder. I can share that in the spirit of public items.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to provide a central server, I would store the Samba shares within /srv. Have a look here: https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard#Directory_structure